# Right Swipe sometimes does not work

Tags: ios, xcode, swipe

I've an app, where the scrolling is done by swiping. Works more or less.

Well, my Code

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeLeft = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(foneFingerSwipeLeft:) ] autorelease];
[oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];
```

and

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeRight = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(foneFingerSwipeRight:) ] autorelease];
[oneFingerSwipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeRight];
```

in my eyes it is exactly the same, except of the Names and directions.
And the same Code is used afterwards again for up and down.

Now the strange behaviour: left, up, down works without any problem, right only works once a while. I got this code from a tutorial and used it with left and right in another app, there it worked without any problem.

Has anyone an idea, how I can resolve this. I've read here a lot questions about this, but most persons have the problem, that it never works, my solution is working in about one of four tries.

Comment: Are you sure the gesture always begins on self.view ?

Comment: well, 100% sure not, but 95%. 
And up, down and left works always, right very seldom.

Comment: What other controls do you have in self.view?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the swipe gesture. Do you have any other controls like ScrollViews in your view? If so, you should take a look at the "canCancelContentTouches" property.

Comment: There are some buttons, but nothing else.